# The quotient of an ideal generated by idempotents of a prime ideal does not contain any idempotents

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let P be a prime ideal in a ring R (commutative with identity) and I be the ideal generated by the idempotents of R, contained in P. Show that R/I contain no idempotents other than 0 and 1.

An approach suggested is to show that for $x$ being one said idempotent in R/I, Then $x(x-1)$ belongs to I.If we then take X ∈ P , then one way suggested in the hint is to show that ∃ y ∈ I and y^2=y such that $yx(x-1)$=$x(x-1)$. I am unable to find this and then show (1-y)x is idempotent which implies x is idempotent

Comment: If $x$ is an idempotent then $x(x-1)=x^2-x=x-x=0$, and $0$ belongs to any ideal...

Comment: It should be in R/I not in R.

Comment: If y is idempotent and (1-y)x is idempotent can we show that x is idempotent?

Comment: I don't think this is true.

Comment: if x belongs to P then it can easily be shown to be true.Only thing left is to prove that there exist such a y